# Race, cross-race, and cross culture tolerance data

Tags: data-request, linked-data, wikidata, state, database

Where can I find since done per-country data on people's attitudes towards people of other race and/or culture living within the same country and children of mixed race living within those countries.

I would like to see some polls, perhaps with a listing of which countries are overall more accepting of these differences and which are more opposed to it (within-country variation data would also be appreciated).

Interesting to see whether age is a contributing factor as well. Other factors would be interesting as well.

P.S. As a result of the recent BREXIT results, this post should be of global concern I suppose.

Comment: Why, do you believe there is a link between the desire to leave a trading bloc and racism?

Comment: gavin add this as a comment, but i flagged bc it is not an answer

Comment: It is an answer to the OP'S PS.

Comment: ok....technically you are correct, but i'll argue its a response, a question at that. so flagging still stands. sorry dude.